# Forma mais eficiente de comparar duas variáveis tipo List

Tags: loop, comparação, groovy

Possuo duas variáveis do tipo `List` que precisam ser comparadas entre si para verificar possíveis duplicatas.

**Exemplo de Conteúdo das Variáveis**

*Variável 01:*
[01, Teste, Ativo]

*Variável 02:*
[01, Teste, Ativo]

No momento estou utilizando o seguinte `script` em Groovy para verificar:

```
for (TransportadoraPostgreSQL transportadorasBDM : transportadorasBanco){
    for(List transportadoraAVerificar : listaTransportadora){
        if (transportadorasBDM.getCodigo().toString().equals(transportadoraAVerificar.get(0).toString())){
            //logger.info("Iguais")
        }
    }
}
```

Porém desse modo quando as duas variáveis tiverem, por exemplo, 100 registros cada uma, serão 10.000 verificações no *Loop*, há alguma forma de ser mais eficiente essa verificação?

Comment: É isso mesmo, a não ser que tivesse algum critério que permite omitir algumas verificação é o que tem que fazer. Por exemplo, vamos dizer que seja garantido que a transportadora aparece só uma vez na lista e você quer apenas saber se existe pelo menos uma coincidência não precisa saber quantas ou quais, aí é possível parar a busca daquele item quando acha o primeiro, mas se só tiver zero ou uma ocorrência em tudo não haverá ganho.

Comment: @bigown E tem como eu deletar o registro repetido, para que na hora de exibir não haja registros repetidos?

Comment: Se voce nao quer que seu array fique duplicado e que seja unico, use `unique()`. por exemplo:

    def a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    def b = [1,2,3,4,5, 6]
    def c = (a + b).unique()

Comment: Ou voce pode tirar a diferenca e somar o array, por exemplo: def a = [1,2,3, 4] 
def b = [1,2,3] 
def c = a + (b - a)​, isto se seu "a" for o array principal.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Except`

```
var firstNotSecond = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
var secondNotFirst = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
```

Esse método é bastante rápido.

```
return !firstNotSecond.Any() && !secondNotFirst.Any();
```

Maiores [informações](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795882/quickest-way-to-compare-two-list/12795900#12795900)

Comment: Isso é Groovy? Parece C#. Além disto o que está sendo feito aí internamente na verdade reproduz o que o código dele faz, com grande chance de menor eficiência, mesmo que pequena diferença. Só tem a otimização que eu comentei ali em cima.